# How to handle very long XPATH? Is there any alternative for this?

Tags: java, xpath, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, service-locator

---

*emphasized text*

//div[@class='preheader']//following-sibling::table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td

Comment: This XPath-1.0 expression is _not_ very long. It should work fine. Optimizations could only be achieved if the XML is known.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the entire heritage of the targeted element isn't significant, it can easily be elided via the `descendent-or-self` axis (`//`) or via element wild cards `*`; either can be combined with predicates, of course:

Here are some examples; you might select via...

- an `id` attribute value: `//td[@id="wantedId"]`
- string value: `//td[.="targeted text"]`
- adjacent text: `//td[preceding-sibling::td[1]="targeted label"]`
- partial heritage: `//div[@id="d1"]/table[@id='t1']//tr[2]/td[1]`

As you can see, however, exactly how to shorten depends upon the context of the targeted node and how that context may vary across document instances.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shorter XPath expression that is precisely equivalent to this one.

There are shorter XPaths that may give the same result on some documents, but there is no XPath that will give the same result on every possible document.

If you're only concerned with one document in particular, then a path like `(//*)[872]` might give you the right element. But usually, the whole point of using XPath is to find an expression that still works if the document is slightly different. To achieve that, it's necessary to know the structure of the class of documents that you want to query; and indeed, the *intent* of the query.